# Previewing SWF File before Uploading

Tags: javascript, html, flash, filereader

I am creating this website that allows user to upload a swf file. 
I am trying to add a functionality that will display the swf file before uploading it,
so the user can confirm if he/she is uploading the right file.

I am currently using FileReader::readAsDataUrl(file) method but it is not working. 
Although it can read the contents the file, it seems like flash player cannot interpret the data
correctly. It says "Movie not loaded" when you right click on it.

Below is the generated html code form javascript.

```
<object width="350" height="350" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="<!--data-->">
    <param name="movie" value="<!--data-->">
    <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always">
</object>
```

I tried changing the data and value part to the url of the same file already uploaded in the server and it worked.
So maybe there is a different way of reading a data from the local pc.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
artsylar

Comment: use embed tag in object tag and check.

Comment: value="flvplayer.swf?file=**video Location**&autoStart=true"  Add this line to your second param.

Comment: thank you @AlpeshPrajapati for your suggestions. I don't know where to add your 2nd comment. I mean which attribute should I set it. and is flvplayer.swf is the name of my file?

Comment: yaa.. replace it with your file. and add my 2nd comment to  "<param name="AllowScriptAccess" value= here "

Comment: I think I cannot specify the full path of the file. We cannot get it now from the input field. we can only get the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after reading the File API documentation. I was able to make it work but only in local pc but NOT in the server.

I used `window.URL.createObjectURL(file)` to get the url of the file and just pass it to the src attribute of embed element.

Comment: What was the problem on the server?

Comment: Hi! I had this problem 3 years ago and I can't remember anymore what was the problem in the server. Based on my comment to another answer to this post, seems like I was able to make it work. "
 
thanks @alpesh! finally I was able to make it work. I followed your advice of using embed then i used window.URL.createObjectURL(file) to get the url and pass it to the src attribute of the embed element. thanks again!"

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" id="Yourfilename" ALIGN="">
    <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="Yourfilename.swf"> 
    <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high> 
    <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#333399>
    <EMBED src="Yourfilename.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#333399 WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" NAME="Yourfilename" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED> 
</OBJECT>
```

Try this and let us know

Comment: thank @alpesh, but there is no way to get the file full path from the input field. that is why the only option i have is to read the File Object and pass it to the object. I was able to do it on image files and text files but not with swf file.

Comment: thanks @alpesh! finally  I was able to make it work. I followed your advice of using embed then i used window.URL.createObjectURL(file) to get the url and pass it to the src attribute of the embed element. thanks again!